# Executar shellscript em um mobile android

Tags: android, shell

Alguém sabe se há um algum app default que faz leitura de shellscript em mobile android? Alguém já tentou fazer algo do tipo?

Comment: Não conheço um app default, mas acredito que você deva ser capaz de enviar um script para o celular e executar através do ADK. Se tudo mais, tem aplicativos no Google Play! pra isso. Com uma busca encontrei este: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.tools.scriptmanager

Comment: Adicionar um apk que faz isto não me ajuda, isto porque eu tenho 36 apk's para serem instalados em 400 tablet's (não via google play). Logo estou tentando encontrar uma forma de automatizar a cópia de package e instalação do apk via script 

Vlw

Comment: Seu problema é sobre instalar apk's em lote ou executar scripts arbitrários? Cuidado para procurar perguntar sobre o seu **problema**, não sobre sua tentativa de solução. Leitura recomendada: [**Problema XY**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu entendi, o que você quer é executar a leitura de arquivos shell script no android e isso você pode fazer como se estivesse no seu pc.
Você pode escrever toda a rotina que você deseja no script e depois executá-lo, ex:

```
$ sh ./seu_script.sh
```

Para saber o path do bash use

```
$ find / -name "bash"
```

ou

```
$ which bash
```